# Return not waiting for if condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, electron

any one can help me.. I am developing a small project in Electron js. as a beginner I could not find any solution for this issue. I have search a lot similar problem discussed but I could not find it.

I want store data locally with Sqlite but when application open in first time in a new system, user should set database location. for that purpose I have write some code in main process and renderer.

here is code in Main process

```js
ipcMain.handle('read-user-data', async (event, fileName) => {

    const checkPath = path.join(app.getPath('userData'), '\Local Storage/config.json')

    const dbPathExist = fs.readJsonSync(checkPath, { throws: false })

    if (dbPathExist === null) {
        dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ['openFile'] })
            .then(dgRresult => {
                if (!dgRresult.canceled) {

                    try {
                        fs.writeJson(checkPath, { dbPath: dgRresult.filePaths[0] })
                        FinaldbPath = dgRresult.filePaths[0]
                        return FinaldbPath

                    } catch (err) {
                        console.error("521: " + err)
                    }

                } else {
                    win.close()
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("522: " + error)
            })
    } else {

        fs.readJson(checkPath)
            .then(packageObj => {
                FinaldbPath = packageObj.dbPath

                console.log(typeof (FinaldbPath))
                return FinaldbPath
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err)
            })
    }
})
```

in render

```js
dbConnection: function () {
    ipcRenderer.invoke('read-user-data')
        .then(dbPath => {
            console.log('invoke is: ' +  dbPath)
        })
}
```

but the result always getting undefined.
I guess problem with async function. but I could not find the right solution

can any one help me

Comment: You use an `async` handle function, but never `await` anything in it? Does `ipcMain.handle` even expect a return value?

Comment: You're not returning anything in your `ipcMain.handle` listener. You should either return a promise or use `await` instead of `then`. I recommend you read more about how promises and async/await work in JavaScript

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay. problem is solved..

Comment: @ShafeequeOT If your problem is solved, then please write that up as an answer, post it and accept it. This could potentially help others in the future. Thanks!

Comment: The issue is that you are mixing `.then` with `await` - instead of using only `await` - and then also not awaiting the resulting promise.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem solved with sync method

here is the corrected code

```js
ipcMain.handle('read-user-data', async (event, fileName) => {

    const checkPath = path.join(app.getPath('userData'), '\Local Storage/config.json')

    const dbPathExist = fs.readJsonSync(checkPath, { throws: false })

    if (dbPathExist === null) {
        selectedPath =  dialog.showOpenDialogSync({ properties: ['openFile'] })
   
        if (selectedPath) {

            try {
                fs.writeJson(checkPath, { dbPath: selectedPath[0] })
                FinaldbPath = selectedPath[0]
                return FinaldbPath

            } catch (err) {
                console.error("521: " + err)
            }


        } else {
            win.close()
        }
 
    } else {

        const packageObj = fs.readJsonSync(checkPath)
        FinaldbPath = packageObj.dbPath

        return FinaldbPath
    }
})
```

Comment: This will block the thread though. It's better to use `await` correctly.